# jQuery.inArray not performing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the following function to check checkboxes based on a set of feature filters, which is an array returned by a separate [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460506/get-url-parameter-value-when-parameter-is-defined-multiple-times).

```
$(function() {
    $('#device_form').find(':checkbox[name^="feature_filters"]').each(function () {
      $(this).prop("checked", (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('data-feature-id'), feature_filters) != -1 ));
      console.log("feature_filters " + jQuery.type(feature_filters) + " " + feature_filters);
      console.log("data-feature-id " + $(this).attr('data-feature-id'));
      console.log("In Array Result " + jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('data-feature-id'), feature_filters));
    });
});
```

The log is interesting:

```
feature_filters array 2,10
data-feature-id 9
-> inArray Result -1

feature_filters array 2,10
data-feature-id 2
-> inArray Result -1
```

As you can see the inArray result should be 0 for the last example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't use parentheses here: `.prop('checked,(...));`

Comment: You're getting data attributes, and they are generally strings, does the array contain numbers ?

Comment: string. I tried using toNum(), but this did not work

Comment: Oh I see I need return parseInt();

Comment: Yes, use `parseInt(value, 10)`, don't forget the radix.

Comment: You should put this as an answer so I may select it:   $(function() {
    $('#device_form').find(':checkbox[name^="feature_filters"]').each(function () {
      num = parseInt($(this).attr('data-feature-id'), 10);
      $(this).prop("checked", (jQuery.inArray(num, feature_filters) != -1 ));
    });
  });

Comment: As array contains all int values when you using `$.inarray()` try to pass same type whats there in array .

Comment: @Abram - If you figured it out, just post the answer yourself, and accept it.

Comment: OK. Well, you led me down the path.. But I'll post it just to make it clear to anyone looking. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @adeneo, I needed to convert `data-feature-id` to integer format in order for inArray to work properly. Here is my answer:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#device_form').find(':checkbox[name^="feature_filters"]').each(function () {
      num = parseInt($(this).attr('data-feature-id'), 10);
      $(this).prop("checked", (jQuery.inArray(num, feature_filters) != -1 ));
    });
  });
```